# priv_sock_get_cmd error with vsftpd

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I've installed `vsftpd` on my local system. When trying to connect to it using filezilla I get following error:

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a post [here](http://chemdroid.net/en/ubuntu/23-vsftpd-500-oops-priv-sock-get-cmd) that describes the problem. The new kernel module `seccomp` is used automatically by `vsftpd` since version 3.0.0. `vsftpd` is a bit buggy when using seccomp.

Add this line to the end of /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
seccomp_sandbox=NO
```

and restart the Server:

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

Comment: link is dead...